# Virtual memory features

Tags: architecture, virtual-memory, segment

I'm getting ready for the computer architecture exam, and I need your help with one exercise.

A simple microprocessor with a 16-bit data bus and a 24-bit address bus supports virtual addressing.
64 pieces of 16 bit register DPPi=0...63 are used.
However, only 14 lower bits are available.
The length of the virtual address is 16 bits. The 6 upper bits indicate one of the 64 registers.
Physical memory is obtained by unifying the 14-bit page address and 10 offset bits.

Questions 
What is the amount of memory in kilobytes of each segment?

My Proposed Answer
2^14 * 16bit=256kb

What is the maximum number of segments in physical memory?

My Presumptive Answer
64*2^14

What is the total amount of physical memory?

My Proposed Answer
64*2^14*256kb

Thank you

[Virtual memory image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SThU2.png)